# Database Table JNDI Name problem

Tags: java, jndi, netbeans7.0

I am using Netbeans 7.0 IDE to create Entity Classes from Database.

When I am requested the JNDI name of the Data Source I am having trouble.

My Database looks like the following:

[image]

Now when trying to create the entity classes from Database:

[image]

It brings the tables corresponding to **mysql** schema right down below **lemm** schema.

Question: Whats the appropriate JNDI name of my **lemm** datasource?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't your jndi name, it's the datasource url.  Change your db connection url to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lemm
```

Comment: What problems are you having?  If you have the correct URL then Netbeans should pick up the tables correctly.